# Using Groovy in SOAPUI, is it possible to generate a GUID with no hyphens?

Tags: groovy, soapui, guid

This is what I have currently:

```
def transactionID = "${java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}";
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('transactionID', transactionID)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UUID has always a form like `0e62c22e-f590-4e9c-9f29-bc7231453da4`, but you can convert it to string and call `String.replaceAll('-','')` to remove all hyphens:

```
def transactionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll('-','')
println transactionID // e.g. ea3b6994ca104d54b7d9b12f32eb7878
```